# Can I use google drive third party authorizing without backend

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

I've developed a website: [online markdown editor](https://renhongl.github.io/markdown-editor/).

It's all front-end, and I want to add Google Drive to store files. I tried to use Google Drive third-party authorize, but I have cross domain issues when trying to get the token by dynamic code

Comment: I recommend you to implement the Drive API as explained in the Quickstart for Javascript in the Google documentation:  https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I do not want to develop any server for my website. this quick start need python support.

Comment: Another possibility would be a WebApp. It is a combined serverside (with access to Drive API) and client side (html/javascript) code piece that can be incorporated by its URL into your website. Have a look: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this. Have you found any solution?